# How to Start Multiple Threads Dynamically by casting variable names as Object

Tags: vb.net, casting, dynamically-generated

Not sure how hard this will be or if casting is involved but here is what i'd like ( vb.net code please )

What I would like is simply a `Loop` that will create different `Threads` with different names.

```
dim variableName="Thread"
for i as Integer = 0 to 5
    "dim " & variableName & (i) & "as new Threading.Thread"
next
```

and then start them

```
for i as integer = 0 to 5
    variableName & i.tostring" = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf SubOrFunction))"
    variableName & i.tostring".Start(s)
```

1. How would one accomplish this
2. What is this actually called ( terminology )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you want to assign names dynamically to objects, it's best to use a dictionary.  In the dictionary, you would use the key for the dynamically assigned name and you would use the value as the object that is assigned that name.  For instance:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, MyClass)()

'Add objects to dictionary
d("dynamic name 1") = New MyClass()
d("dynamic name 2") = New MyClass()

'Get object from dictionary by name
Dim myObject As MyClass = d("dynamic name 1")
```

The same method will work well with threads, for instance:

```
Dim threads As New Dictionary(Of String, Thread)()
Dim variableName = "Thread"
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    threads(variableName & "(" & i.ToString() & ")") = New Thread()
Next
```

However, if all you are doing is assigning numeric indexes to them, rather than string names, you could just use a list instead, like this:

```
Dim threads As New List(Of Thread)()
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    threads.Add(New Thread())
Next
```

Then you could get the thread from the list by index like this:

```
Dim t As Thread = threads(1)
```

Or, if you have a set number of threads, you could easily use an array:

```
Dim threads(4) As Thread
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    threads(i) = New Thread()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Dictonary(of String, Thread)` so can you easily access them

```
Dim dictThread as new Dictionary(of String, Thread)
For i as integer = 0 to 5
   dictThread.add("Thread" & i.toString, New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf SubOrFunction))
Next
```

Start 'em

```
For Each t as Thread in dictThread.Values
   t.Start(WhateverSIs)
Next
```

Or Start specific thread: `dictThread("Thread3").Start(s)`

Note: Just written, not tested ;)