# Multi threading for one process vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, process

I just learned some basics of multi threading in VB.net recently as i need to Multi threading for one  process
my code is :

```html
Private Sub btnLoadNow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim T1 As New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
    T1.Start()

    Dim T2 As New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
    T2.Start()

    Dim T3 As New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
    T3.Start()

    Dim T4 As New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
    T4.Start()

    Dim T5 As New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
    T5.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub myprocess()
   'my Process Codes

End Sub
```

but this code have error how can i make it?

Comment: "this code have error" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You dont have defined **AutoLoad**.

```
Dim T1 As New Thread(AddressOf AutoLoad)
```

Just replace AutoLoad --->  myprocess

```
Dim T1 As New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
```

**AND**

```
Private Sub myprocess()
   'my Process Codes
Next
```

**Sub have to end with End Sub**

```
Private Sub myprocess()
       'my Process Codes
End Sub
```

**THIS CODE IS WORKING**

```
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim T1, T2, T3, T4 As Thread

        T1 = New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
        T2 = New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
        T3 = New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)
        T4 = New Thread(AddressOf myprocess)

        T1.Start()
        T2.Start()
        T3.Start()
        T4.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub myprocess()
      'some code
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: in my process have listbox and textbox and.... and i cant use module how can i make Multi threading for one process

Comment: Pls share more code because i dont know what you want to do.

Comment: I use module because my application is console. You have to use Class

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: dont have example try find some example here

Comment: can you give me a example i can not find it?

Comment: For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533135/how-to-start-multiple-threads-dynamically-by-casting-variable-names-as-object

Comment: for example,i need 100 thread for one process for speed up it how can i make it? please help me i search it in google but i can not find it

Comment: @AMIRHOSSEINRAHIMI : Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. Search Google more or by a programming book.